# Copy plot "caracteristics" from a class to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to know if it's possible to copy plotting caracteristics from a figure to another. Here an example:

You have a first plot, made in a method of the class "A", where curves are plotted , xlim and a grid are defined:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.plot()
   def plot(self):
       test1=[[1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15], [1,1,1,1, 5,5,5,5], [0,11,20,30,0,11,20,30]] 
       self.data=pd.DataFrame(test1).T
       ax = plt.gca()
       self.data.plot(ax=ax)

       ax.set_xlim(0, 40)

       n_x,n_y=11,8.5
       ax.set_aspect( ax.get_xlim()[1]/ax.get_ylim()[1] * n_y/n_x  ) 
       # Customize the major grid
       ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1.1', color='black')
       # Customize the minor grid
       ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
```

Then you have another class "B", on another file :

```
 class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.plot()
   def plot(self):
       test2=[[2.55,6.55,0.33], [1.2,2.2,2.3]] 
       self.data=pd.DataFrame(test2).T
       self.data.plot()
```

if i call the class A can i copy the grid and xlim without doing it again in class B? Like creating a variable that contain all thoses caracteristics ?

And can I for example defines thoses xlim and grid without plotting in the class A and only plot in the class B? Indeed the class B is in a GUI file where i did an interface with Tkinter and i want to plot curves from the other file inside it .

Hope my answer is a bit clear ^^ Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably rather create one single class that gets fed in different data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

class Base():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(test1).T

    def plot(self, ax=None):
        ax = ax or plt.gca()
        self.data.plot(ax=ax)
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

        n_x,n_y=11,8.5
        ax.set_aspect( ax.get_xlim()[1]/ax.get_ylim()[1] * n_y/n_x  )  
        ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1.1', color='black')
        ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')


test1=[[1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15], [1,1,1,1, 5,5,5,5], [0,11,20,30,0,11,20,30]] 
test2=[[2.55,6.55,0.33], [1.2,2.2,2.3]] 

b1 = Base(test1)
b2 = Base(test2)
b1.plot()
b2.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The thing is the first class is in a GUI file where i did an interface with Tkinter (represented by class B) and where i want to incorporate curves made in the other file (where is class A). Also I'D like to know if it's possible to define grid and xlim in the plot file and call them in the GUI

Comment: Don't mix the plotting with the GUI interface.

Comment: so how can i import the curves in the interface and all caracteristics defined in the "plot file" in my interface?

Comment: I think I don't understand the problem.